# How can I cange default voice engine for my app?

Tags: actions-on-google

While creating registering app, I'd chosen a random voice.
But now, how can I change default voice for my app?
I can't find it in settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the actions console at https://console.actions.google.com/

Make sure you are in the Overview section

[image]

Select the edit pencil to the right of your Action's name

[image]

Click to edit the App Information

[image]

Expand the Details section

[image]

You should now be able to edit the Assistant app voice through the dropdown

[image]